# Dividing a character with a Float in Ada

Tags: type-conversion, character, ada

So i´m trying to divide a character with a float using an operator, but I dont know why my code gets the error message "unexpected argument for "Position" attribute"

```
function "/"(Teck: in Character;
             Flyt: in Float) return Float is
  
  
begin
  
  return Float(Character'Position(Teck))/Flyt;
  
end "/";
```

Can somebody explain how Character'position works and what I need to change here, because I´ve used pretty much the same code previously in a different assigment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the [ARM](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-3-3.html), characters are, for example, defined as

```ada
UC_C_Cedilla               : constant Character := 'Ç'; --Character'Val(199)
```

And if you read the operations on discrete types in the [ARM](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-5.html), you'll se that the inverse attribute of *Val* is *Pos*, not *Position*.

Comment: haha yes, cant believe I made a dumb mistake like that. Thank you!